# Facebook Adding friend as test user

Tags: facebook

I am currently developing an app on Facebook. I understand that you can add friends as test users under 'Roles' where the app is managed. However, when I add someone as a test user, they don't get any kind of notification and cannot find the app from their Facebook page.

This is my first Facebook app and it needs to involve users pictures, and the amount of likes a picture has etc. Therefore, it would be easier for me to test with a real user rather than setting up a load of fake test users and making them like each others pictures.

Any insight or information as to why this invite isn't working or how the user would access my app would be greatly appreciated.

(The app is in development mode - not sure if that is relevant)

Comment: Is the friend registered as a developer already? If not, they need to go to https://developers.facebook.com/ and do so first.

Comment: They weren't originally. But I have registered them as a developer, and resent the request. Still no luck though.

Comment: Have them check https://developers.facebook.com/requests/ – any pending request should be shown there. Ohterwise, if they really are registered as a developer (otherwise they should get a message when trying to access aforementioned page) – file a bug report, so FB looks into it: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Just reported it as a bug :)